# Build a tree / run recursive query in Kusto Azure Data Explorer

Tags: recursion, azure-data-explorer

I have a Kusto table that has the following structure:

| Name | File | IngestType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | F1 | output |
| B | F1 | input |
| B | F2 | output |
| C | F2 | input |
| D | F2 | input |

I want to start with a given Name, say `A` and run a query where I can build a flat tree up to a certain level. So far my solution is to write a query for each level and union the data in the end:

```
    let parent = table | where Name == 'A';
    let child_level_1 = table | where type == 'input' 
    | join kind=inner parent on File
    | ... // project own output logic for child_level_2 to consume
    let child_level_2 = table | where type == 'input'
    | join kind=inner child_level_1 on File
    ...
    let child_level_10 = ...
```

Could the above be built dynamically in Kusto? Something on the lines of "while children have outputs consumed by others, keep query-ing"

Comment: So Kusto has nothing corresponding to recursive common table expressions in SQL (`WITH RECURSIVE`)? These are really misnamed, they're iterative rather than recursive, but serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the above be built dynamically in Kusto? Something on the lines of "while children have outputs consumed by others, keep query-ing"

No. What you wrote above (using child_level_i) is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

Kusto supports now directed graph, which would allow you to achieve what you want by building a process tree then filtering out branches
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/graph-operators

Have a look there:
https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language/issues/133#issuecomment-1868939619

## Old way

if you are looking for a particular process branch, you could target it by defining the process tree as a time sequence of processes launched or command-lines with [evaluate sequence_detect plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sequence-detect-plugin).

```
datatable (Time: datetime, parent:string, child: string)[
    '2023-01-13T14:01:06.3120799Z', "Grand parent", "parent",
    '2023-01-13T14:01:07.3120799Z', "parent", "child",
    '2023-01-13T14:01:08.3120799Z', "child", "grand child",
    '2023-01-13T14:01:08.3120799Z', "noise parent", "noise child"
    '2023-01-13T14:01:08.3120799Z', "noise child", "noise grandchild"
    ]
| evaluate sequence_detect(Time, // time column to look for sequence
                            3s, // timespan  allowed for the sequence completion
                            2s, // max timespan between each step
                           // process tree as condition
                           GrandParentFound =  parent == "Grand parent" and child == "parent",
                            ParentFound = parent == "parent" and child == "child",
                            ChildFound = parent == "child" and child == "grand child"
                            )
```